# SQL 2012 statement to return Lookup Values in Ranges

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

So I have 2 tables,

```
Table A has 3 columns: 
    NumberRangeStart, NumberRangeEnd, RangeName
Table B has 2 columns: 
    Number, RangeName
```

I want an output to

```
TableC:
    B.Number, B.RangeName, A.NumberRange, A.RangeName
```

I want to Find where `B.Number` falls between `A.NumberRangeStart and A.NumberRangeEnd`, and report the `RangeName` assigned.

any Idea How to acheive this in SQL 2012 ?
I think I need a CTE, but unsure of how to go about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #TableA (
    NumberRangeStart int,
    NumberRangeEnd int,
    RangeName nvarchar(200))

create table #TableB (
    Number int)

insert into #TableA values (0, 100, '0 to 100'), (50, 70, '50 to 70'), (150, 1000, '150 to 1000')

insert into #TableB values (10), (20), (40), (60), (200), (2000)

select  b.Number, coalesce(a.Rangename, 'Not in any range')
from    #TableB b left join #TableA a on b.Number between a.NumberRangeStart and a.NumberRangeEnd
```

Comment: Hmm, Joining with a between statement, hadn't thought of that! I'll try that paul. thanks!

Comment: worked like a charm Thank you!  - didn't think you could join on an Between statement... not sure why. :)

Answer (score 1):

This reads like a simple two condition inner join used within an insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO TableC
SELECT
    TableB.Number,
    TableB.RangeName,
    TableA.NumberRangeStart,
    TableA.NumberRangeEnd,
    TableA.RangeName
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.Number BETWEEN TableA.NumberRangeStart AND TableA.NumberRangeEnd
-- Optional based on clarification
WHERE TableA.RangeName <> TableB.RangeName;
```

Comment: Hi jtimberley, thanks for the response, Unfortunately, I cannot join on Rangename. It's the Differences in Rangename between the two tables I am looking for...The Relationship between the two tables is that TableB .Number  MAY fall into the Range of TableA

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.RangeName
FROM TableB B
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM TableA A
    WHERE A.RangeName = B.RangeName
    AND   B.Number BETWEEN A.NumberRangeStart AND A.NumberRangeEnd
)
```